# Rendering unescaped characters in javascript using thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, java, thymeleaf

I'm using a StringBuilder from my java controller to dynamically build a string of objects from my database for use in a JavaScript script on a Thymeleaf template web page.

Is there any way to keep an escaped quotation in java from processing as `&quot;`from Thymeleaf? I need the quotes to escape the date string in the JavaScript code.

Edit: Specifically the statement `"\""` renders as `&quot;` rather than `"`.

String building method:

```
private String getDataPoints() {
        ArrayList<WeightEntry> data = (ArrayList<WeightEntry>) repo.findAll();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(data.get(i).getDate().toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
            LocalDate calender = LocalDate.of(date.getYear(), date.getMonthValue(), date.getDayOfMonth());
            sb.append("{ label: \"" + calender.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy")) + "\",  y: " + data.get(i).getWeight() + "  }");
            if (i < data.size() - 1) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
        }
        
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Javacript with template

```
dataPoints: [
                [[${dataPoints}]]
            ]
```

Expected Output:

```
dataPoints: [
                { label: "02-Sep-20",  y: 160.0  }, { label: "08-Sep-20",  y: 125.0  }
            ]
```

Actual output from browser console

```
dataPoints: [
                { label: &quot;02-Sep-20&quot;,  y: 160.0  }, { label: &quot;08-Sep-20&quot;,  y: 125.0  }
            ]
```

I am using spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.3.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because Thymeleaf doesn't know you are outputting JavaScript, but thinks it's HTML. A simple solution would be to use Thymeleaf's non-escaped inline syntax which is `[( ... )]`. (See [Expression Inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#expression-inlining).)

```js
dataPoints: [
    [(${dataPoints})]
]
```

However instead of building the output string yourself (which can lead to security issues if you make a mistake when escaping), it would be better to let Thymeleaf build the JavaScript expression for you. (See [Advanced inlined evaluation and JavaScript serialization](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#advanced-inlined-evaluation-and-javascript-serialization)) Just create a normal Java `List` containing `Map`s and Thymeleaf will automatically output it as an array containing objects:

```java
private List<Map<String, Object>> getDataPoints() {
    ArrayList<WeightEntry> data = (ArrayList<WeightEntry>) repo.findAll();

    List<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<>(data.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(data.get(i).getDate().toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        LocalDate calender = LocalDate.of(date.getYear(), date.getMonthValue(), date.getDayOfMonth());

        Map<String, Object> entry = new HashMap<>();
        entry.put("label", calender.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy")));
        entry.put("y", data.get(i).getWeight());

        result.add(entry);
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

For this you also need to tell Thymeleaf that you outputting Javascript, by putting the attribute `th:inline` on the surroundting script element. Also don't add the array brackets yourself. Thymelead will create them for you:

```html
<script th:inline="javascript">
  // ...
  dataPoints: [[${dataPoints}]]
  //...
</script>
```